# Facebook Ads creative object returns story_id that throws a GraphMethodException 100 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I am building a data warehouse that pulls data from both the OG Insights and Ads API.

**Issue:**
I am querying the creative object in the Ads API which returns the `story_id` field for type 27 ads. For most `story_ids` that are returned I am able to do a OG query for the `story_id` and have a valid response returned. However, for some `story_ids` I get `GraphMethodException`.

**Creative query:**

> https://graph.facebook.com/6003446971120?access_token=TOKEN

The token has been exchanged with user who created the ad and has advertiser role on the page which the `story_id` was posted to (based on the `object_id` of the creative). The token has the following scope: `ads_management` `email` `manage_pages` `offline_access` `read_insights`

**Creative query returns:**

> {
>    "url_tags": "", 
>     "story_id": "123 - example", 
>     "type": 27, 
>     "object_id": "456 - example", 
>     "name": "REMOVED", 
>     "run_status": REMOVED, 
>     "preview_url": "REMOVED", 
>     "count_current_adgroups": REMOVED, 
>     "id": "REMOVED", 
>     "creative_id": "REMOVED"
>   }

**Query for story_id:**

> https://graph.facebook.com/123?token=TOKEN

I have tried 2 tokens, the first the the same as above, and the second is for a user that has the `read_insights` role on the project and has the following scope: `ads_management` `manage_pages` `read_insights`

**Story_id query returns:**

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
>       "type": "GraphMethodException", 
>       "code": 100
>     }
>   }

It looks there have been many posts on the `GraphMethodException` error. The common issue is that the token is from a person that is restricted from seeing the content (page age wall, targeted post, ect). However, I think I should have full access to the page based on my privileges. I tried to validate this by having the page manager do the same query, which also returned the `GraphMethodException` error.

So the net net is - How can I have an creative referring to a `story_id` which I cannot get a valid response for?

Thanks guys,

Aaron

PS - I also tried querying `456_123` (the `pageid_postid` format a post) and I still get the same result.

Comment: Are you sure the story still exists? Is it possible someone deleted the story?

Answer (score 0):

This exception does not necessarily relate to access permissions but can also mean that the object cannot be accessed.

For example, it is possible that a creative references a story which has been deleted. In this case, you will not be able to read the details of the story from the Graph API and this exception will be thrown.

You should check whether the story does exist or not by reading the graph for the page that this story was created under.

Comment: Hey Paul - thanks for the response. I have read the page using page/posts and am not finding it there. Do you think this means that the object has been deleted?